# How can I get the nearset point of Delaunay Triangle in Python?

Tags: python, matlab, nearest-neighbor, delaunay

In Matlab,I can use function DelaunayTri and nearestNeighbors to find the nearest point. The code like this:

```
X1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]';
Y1=[1.3,1.5,1.7,1.9,2.1,2.3,2.5]';
Triangulation=DelaunayTri(Y1, X1);

X2=[1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,5.5]';
Y2=[1.2,2.2,3.2,4.2,5.2]';
NearInd = nearestNeighbor(Triangulation, Y2, X2);
NearPoint = [X1(NearInd), Y1(NearInd)];
```

What function should I use in Python to get the same result?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use the [`scipy.spatial.Delaunay`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Delaunay.html#scipy.spatial.Delaunay) module for triangulation.
2. But to query for nearest neighbors you may have to use [`scipy.spatial.cKDTree`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html). This is separate from the triangulation.
3. There are also [CGAL](https://www.cgal.org/) bindings available for python [here](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal-swig-bindings/tree/master/examples/python). But if you are not already familiar with CGAL there may be some learning curve.
4. Then there is also [OpenCV for Python](https://www.learnopencv.com/delaunay-triangulation-and-voronoi-diagram-using-opencv-c-python/) example for triangulation only.
5. There is also [PyHull](https://pythonhosted.org/pyhull/pyhull.html#module-pyhull) the python bindings for [Qhull](http://www.qhull.org/html/qhull.htm). But again I don't see neighbor search anywhere.
6. [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html) has neighbor search too but no triangulation.